# How can I construct a UTF-16 character in JavaScript from the surrogate pair?

Tags: javascript, unicode

The following calculates the UTF-16 surrogate pair for a Unicode codepoint ([Face with Medical Mask](https://emojipedia.org/face-with-medical-mask/)).

But how can I then construct the character from the surrogate pair, for use in a string?

```js
const codepoint = 0b11111011000110111 // 
const tmp = codepoint - 0x10000
const padded = tmp.toString(2).padStart(20, '0')
const unit1 = (Number.parseInt(padded.substr(0, 10), 2) + 0xD800).toString(16)
const unit2 = (Number.parseInt(padded.substr(10), 2) + 0xDC00).toString(16)

// obviously hard-coding the values works...
console.log(`Hard-coded: \ud83d\ude37`)
// ...but how to combine unit1 and unit2 to print the character?
console.log(`Dynamic: unit1: ${unit1}, unit2: ${unit2}`)
```

Comment: I updated my answer. I walked away from my desk and remembered that `fromCharCode` accepts multiple code units, so no need to call it twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two answers for you:

### You may not have to

In a modern JavaScript environment you don't have to split the code point apart, you can use `String.fromCodePoint` to create the character directly:

```
const ch = String.fromCodePoint(codepoint);
```

Live Example:

```js
const codepoint = 0b11111011000110111; // 
const ch = String.fromCodePoint(codepoint);

console.log(ch);
```

### You can build it from parts

If you don't have `fromCodePoint` or you have the surrogates as your starting point, you can get the string version of each surrogate via `fromCharCode` — but don't do `toString(16)`, leave the units as numbers:

```
const unit1 = Number.parseInt(padded.substr(0, 10), 2) + 0xD800;
const unit2 = Number.parseInt(padded.substr(10), 2) + 0xDC00;

const ch = String.fromCharCode(unit1, unit2);
```

Live Example:

```js
const codepoint = 0b11111011000110111 // 
const tmp = codepoint - 0x10000
const padded = tmp.toString(2).padStart(20, '0')
const unit1 = Number.parseInt(padded.substr(0, 10), 2) + 0xD800;
const unit2 = Number.parseInt(padded.substr(10), 2) + 0xDC00;

const ch = String.fromCharCode(unit1, unit2);

console.log(ch);
```

You could even do it as

```
const ch = String.fromCharCode(unit1) + String.fromCharCode(unit2);
```

...but since `fromCharCode` accepts multiple char codes (code units), it probably makes more sense to pass both of them to it at once.

The fact it works with each in isolation (`String.fromCharCode(unit1) + String.fromCharCode(unit2)`) may seem really, really weird. "You mean `String.fromCharCode` happily creates a string with just **half** of a surrogate pair?!" Yup. :-) JavaScript strings are sequences of UTF-16 code units **but** they tolerate invalid or orphaned surrogate pairs. From [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type):

> The String type is the set of all ordered sequences of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer values (“elements”) up to a maximum length of 2<sup>53</sup> - 1 elements. The String type is generally used to represent textual data in a running ECMAScript program, in which case each element in the String is treated as a UTF-16 code unit value. ...
>
> ECMAScript operations that do not interpret String contents apply no further semantics. Operations that do interpret String values treat each element as a single UTF-16 code unit. **However, ECMAScript does not restrict the value of or relationships between these code units**, so operations that further interpret String contents as sequences of Unicode code points encoded in UTF-16 must account for ill-formed subsequences. ...

*(my emphasis)*