# How do I apply a skin tone to an emoji in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

Given this emoji, how can I programmatically apply a skin tone in JavaScript?

Grinning face is `0x1F600`.

Dark Skin Tone is `0x1F3FF`.

Do I simply concatenate the values together?

The following code, based on the algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60324908/how-can-i-construct-a-utf-16-character-in-javascript-from-the-surrogate-pair), merely prints two characters out.

```js
function units(codepoint) {
    const tmp = codepoint - 0x10000
    const padded = tmp.toString(2).padStart(20, '0')
    const unit1 = Number.parseInt(padded.substr(0, 10), 2) + 0xD800;
    const unit2 = Number.parseInt(padded.substr(10), 2) + 0xDC00;
    return [unit1, unit2]
}

const face = units(0x1F600)
const tone = units(0x1F3FF)
const ch = String.fromCharCode(...face, ...tone) 
console.log(ch) //
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only few emojis that actually take up Skin Tones. For example, faces - man and women facepalming:

```js
function units(codepoint) {
    const tmp = codepoint - 0x10000
    const padded = tmp.toString(2).padStart(20, '0')
    const unit1 = Number.parseInt(padded.substr(0, 10), 2) + 0xD800;
    const unit2 = Number.parseInt(padded.substr(10), 2) + 0xDC00;
    return [unit1, unit2]
}

const face = units(0x1F926)
const tone = units(0x1F3FF)
const ch = String.fromCharCode(...face, ...tone) 
console.log(ch)
```

It's not possible with others that do not support colour variants. Here, in [Every Emoji by Codepoint](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/), you can find those **support** the **Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick**.

**No Modifier Support**

[image: nomod]

**Modifier Supported**

[image: yesmod]

Comment: So "Grinning Face" does not support the skin tone?

Comment: @BenAston Yes, that's right, it doesn't support the skin tone, in right way to tell, it doesn't support Emoji Modifier Fitzpatrick.